# Starting vim from Windows PowerShell

Tags: windows-7, windows, vim, powershell

This isn't necessarily a problem, I'm more curious why this behavior occurs.

When attempting to launch vim from powershell, I'm greeted with the `Open with` window:

```
PS C:\> vim
```

[image]

If I specify:

```
PS C:\> vim.exe
```

Vim launches as expected. gVim launches as expected no matter if I specify:

```
PS C:\> gvim.exe
```

or

```
PS C:\> gvim
```

Again, it's not really problem, I just want to know why it happens and what I should look into to get consistent behavior when launching both vim and gvim from powershell.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's probably a file called `vim.` that appears in the Path before `vim.exe` (or it's in the local folder you're trying to launch `vim` from) so it's getting called first when you type `vim`.

Comment: That was it, thanks! The file was created as part of the [Git](http://git-scm.com/downloads) install for Windows: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\vim`. There are other similar files for various GNU tools that exhibit the same behavior.

Answer (score 3):

create alias for vim

```
      Set-Alias vim ' C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim74\gvim.exe'
      Set-Alias vi ' C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim74\gvim.exe'
```

you can change the path if installed in different directory.

Comment: `gvim` is a different application than `vim` and `vi`. There are times when I want to edit in a separate window, and times when I'd like to edit in the command window.

Comment: yes @beargle,  you are right with the console vim and the graphical vim (gvim)

I would like to recommend the console vi editor

[1] (ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/pc/vim74w32.zip)

Later you can set alias to the executable of that.
Yes you can run it on your console window. :)